# Can I make Bazel always output errors on tests from a rule?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, bazel, junit5

I want to make it so that every time I run `bazel test` in my project, I can see errors in the console. This is the equivalent of passing `--test_output=errors` as a flag every time, but I was wondering if there is a way I can do it from within my `java_test` rule so that I don't have to pass that flag every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this can be set on a per target basis, however Bazel can take options from a [`.bazelrc`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/guide.html#bazelrc) file which can be added to the project.

A `.bazelrc` file could be added with the following contents:

```
test --test_output=errors
```

Which would set the `--test_output` flag for the `test` command.